# How should I expose a transactional service, measuring methods invocation times, with separation of concerns in mind?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I'm working on an application created with SpringBoot. What I'm trying to achieve is a layered application, with separation of concerns in each layer.
One of the layers (Gradle module) is an Application layer, where I define an application service:

```
public class TagApplicationService {

    public TagResult getTag(UUID tagId) {
        ...
    }

    public TagResult createTag(CreateTagCommand createTagCommand) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In another Gradle module, responsible for setting up Spring context, which depends on the application module, I define a configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = "application.tag",
        includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                classes = {
                        TagApplicationService.class
                }
        )
)
class ApplicationConfiguration {
}
```

Having separation of concerns in mind (I don't want the application module to have any Spring/JPA/Micrometer related dependencies), how can I make the produced bean transactional?
I would also like to collect metrics about the invocation times of methods of TagApplicationService with Micrometer and expose them with Actuator.

I tried to extend the TagApplicationService in Spring module and make the new class transactional. But I believe there must be a better way. The solution doesn't solve the problem of metrics collection, which I would like not to mix with the responsibility of making the bean transactional.

```
@Transactional
@Service
class TransactionalTagApplicationService extends TagApplicationService {
    public TagResult getTag(UUID tagId) {
        return super.getTag(tagId);
    }

    public TagResult createTag(CreateTagCommand createTagCommand) {
        return super.createTag(createTagCommand);
    }
}
```

Comment: Step back and rethink. You are overengineering and making things overly complex. Rethink your definition of separation of concerns.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your interest in my question.
I agree, I'm overengineering. What I do is I try to create a hobby project where I implement what I learned from Clean Architecture book by Uncle Bob. I agree that this is not a pragmatic approach. But this is my understanding of what the application layer should do: it should not be responsible for instrumentation, just interaction with the domain layer.